# Perform logical check to the grouped query result

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have data set as follows,

```
job_id | status 
-------|-------
  100  |   0
  100  |   0
  102  |   1
  102  |   0
  104  |   1
  104  |   1
---------------
```

the query to process the data

```
SELECT job_id, (CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(0, GROUP_CONCAT(status)) > 0 THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END) AS isfinished
FROM mytable
GROUP BY job_id
```

and the result is

```
job_id | isfinished
-------|-----------
  100  |     0
  102  |     0
  104  |     1
-------------------
```

Has anyone ever done this? Perhaps with a better approach.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to see if the minimum value is bigger than 0.

```
SELECT job_id, min(status) > 0 AS isfinished
FROM mytable
GROUP BY job_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4792/4

Comment: @hims056, ... thanks for quick response, status represent the "work order status" of each job_id, "1" means "done". The job_id could be closed only if all the work order status has been done.

Comment: Right, my query will give the same result as yours and might be clearer to some. If you have a lot of rows per job_id find_in_set might be slower than min.

Comment: indeed ... simpler and easier to understand than mine.